# update maximum slider element input type=text

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider

trying to learn to understand jquery more and need a solution to problem.  Initially I have drop down menu.  With an onchange action in this I want to dynamically update the data-slider-max='mychoice'  here's an attempt below

```
             function changeFunc($i) {

               var mySlider = $("input#slider").slider();

                     mySlider.slider('setAttribute','data-slider-max',$i);

                }

               </script>

               <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc(value);">
                <option value="100" selected=selected>Option #1</option>
                <option value="200">Option #2</option>
               </select>
       <div id="slider-wrap">
            <div id="minus"><img src="../images/slider-minus.png" alt=""/></div>             
            <input type="text" id="slider" value="" data-slider-min="5"           data-slider-max="Changethis" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="15" data-slider-precision="2" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
            <div id="plus"><img src="../images/slider-plus.png" alt=""/></div>
            <div id="slider-value"><span>£</span><input id='edit-slider-value' name="slidervalue" type="text" value="7.50"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to set a new value for that attribute you can do this.

```
function changeFunc($i) {

    var mySlider = $("input#slider");

    mySlider.attr('data-slider-max', $i);

}
```